# Fire Event When Javascript InnerText Value Meet If Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get innerText value and use it in if statement. Something like that :
Hypertext codes

```
<div class="demo">
  <h2 id="txt"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true" id="icon"></i>
    Male
</h2>
</div>
```

Javascript Codes:

```
    var parentdiv = $( "#txt" ).text();
    if (parentdiv == 'Male'){
      $( "#icon" ).attr( "class", "fa fa-male" );
    }else {
      $( "#icon" ).attr( "class", "fa fa-female" );
    }
```

it isn't working why? Give me a Solution please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? A simple log statement might help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retrieved text content contains whitespace in both end so use [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) or [`jQuery.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method to replace the trailing and leading space.

```
var parentdiv = $( "#txt" ).text().trim();
// or
var parentdiv = $.trim($( "#txt" ).text());
```